# How to read message from SQS dead letter queue using Nodejs

Tags: amazon-sqs

I created a dead letter queue for my queue using Redrive Policy. All I have is an ARN, (which is exactly the same with my queue's ARN).

I wonder how to read / remove the messages in DLQ using Nodejs. What I want to achieve is an endpoint to retrieve all dead messages, and an endpoint to purge the DLQ.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

You read messages from a DLQ in exactly the same way that you read them from any other queue.

If you already know how to read and delete messages from a non-DLQ, the DLQ is used the same way.